# Merge video and audio using ffmpeg and download immediately in django

Tags: python, django, ffmpeg

I have video and audio file which is to be merge and download immediately. I have written some code but it will start download after merged. I want when user hit the url, then it will start merging and downloading immediately so that user don't have to wait for it.

```
video_url = "./video.mp4"
audio_url = "./audio.mp4"

output_filepath = './merged.mp4'

try:
    process = subprocess.Popen([
        "ffmpeg",
        "-i", video_url,
        "-i", audio_url,
        "-c:v", "copy",
        "-c:a", "copy",
        "-f", "mp4",
        "-movflags", "frag_keyframe+empty_moov",
        "pipe:1"
    ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    def generate_stream():
        while True:
            data = process.stdout.read(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            yield data

    response = StreamingHttpResponse(generate_stream(), content_type="video/mp4")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="stream.mp4"'
    return response

except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    return HttpResponse("Error: {}".format(e), status=500)
```

But it will merge and then start downloading. I  want to be at same time so that user don't have to wait until the merging process.

I am using django and i am learning django